# Something so weird while using netsh

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, netsh

While using netsh, I am in an enterprise network and there are multiple bssids in the network, my device connects to the one that has the best signal by default behaviour as you know. (this is a big university)... when I run

```
netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid
```

I wanted to get the bssids of different modems that is serving the same ssid. It is so weird the output is like below ( i  never moved the location of my laptop ) first time I ran it it ONLY gave 1 BSSID, the second time I ran it, it gave multiple BSSID and more networks, (I couldnt put the all output since it was long...) BUT THE NEXT TIMES i ran it it again just gave 1 BSSID.. Isn't this so weird behaviour since i didnt change location and didn't change any settings on the laptop ?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.2715]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\ibera> netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid

Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SABANCIUNIV
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Enterprise
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:ba:d0
         Signal             : 87%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 116
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         1
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54


C:\Users\ibera> netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid

Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 2 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SABANCIUNIV
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Enterprise
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : a8:ff:ba:cb:b2:20
         Signal             : 81%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 2.4 GHz
         Channel            : 11
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         0
             Channel Utilization:        25 (9 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2
         Other rates (Mbps) : 5.5 6 9 11 12 18 24 36 48 54
    BSSID 2                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:cb:b0
         Signal             : 31%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 108
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         1
             Channel Utilization:        0 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
    BSSID 3                 : a8:ff:ba:cb:b2:30
         Signal             : 46%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 52
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         3
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
    BSSID 4                 : a8:ff:ba:cd:32:f0
         Signal             : 65%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 100
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         1
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
    BSSID 5                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:d1:e0
         Signal             : 70%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 2.4 GHz
         Channel            : 1
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         0
             Channel Utilization:        17 (6 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2
         Other rates (Mbps) : 5.5 6 9 11 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

and again if i kept running..

```
C:\Users\ibera> netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid

Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SABANCIUNIV
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Enterprise
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:ba:d0
         Signal             : 87%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 116
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         2
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54


C:\Users\ibera>netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid

Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SABANCIUNIV
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Enterprise
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:ba:d0
         Signal             : 87%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 116
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         2
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54


C:\Users\ibera>netsh wlan show network mode=Bssid

Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : SABANCIUNIV
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Enterprise
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : a8:ff:ba:cc:ba:d0
         Signal             : 87%
         Radio type         : 802.11ax
         Band               : 5 GHz
         Channel            : 116
         Bss Load:
             Connected Stations:         2
             Channel Utilization:        2 (0 %)
             Medium Available Capacity:  30000 (960000 us/s)
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 6 12 24
         Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
```

Why is this happening, how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Many networks around means lots of conflicting transmitters and perhaps noise-emitting magnetic fields. Fluctuating reception strength is one explanation.

Comment: `how to solve this issue ?` ... what is the issue?